# About the database used by netbox

Tags: python, java, postgresql, netbox

Is the database used by netbox PostgreSQL?

Our virtual machine base information is stored inside netbox. We need Java to go to netbox to create VM information and to get VM information. But this does not guarantee transactivity. So we want to use Java to connect to netbox's database for transactional operations.

Our virtual machine base information is stored inside netbox. We need Java to go to netbox to create VM information and to get VM information. But this does not guarantee transactivity. So we want to use Java to connect to netbox's database for transactional operations.

Comment: Looks like it: https://docs.netbox.dev/en/stable/administration/replicating-netbox/

Answer (score 0):

Yes netbox uses PostgreSQL as a Database

Answer (score 0):

While it's entirely possible to directly interact with the database directly your better approach will likely be interacting through the API.  It's quite robust and easy to interact with (as far as APIs go).